# How do I scale up/enlarge RecyclerView items only when they are the most centered and shrink them when user swipes away

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I scale up/enlarge RecyclerView items only when they are the most centered and shrink them when user swipes away?

I was able to achieve that with a ViewPager like so:

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

                final float normalizedPosition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
                page.setScaleX(normalizedPosition / 2 + 0.7f);
                page.setScaleY(normalizedPosition / 2 + 0.7f);
                page.setPadding(-dpToPx(40), 0, -dpToPx(40), 0);
            }
        });
```

But I had to rewrite the functionality and now I am using a horizontal recycler view.

I was able to set a scroll listener to the RecyclerView and scale up the current view, but I don't know how to scale it down when it goes out of focus